# Universal link in an iOS device does not open the app

Tags: flutter, branch.io

Our team is building a mobile application using flutter and branch.io. We followed the Getting Started tutorial https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration#configure-bundle-identifier. Everything is going right until we press a universal link in an iOS device. The link always open the custom url instead of opening the app. Do you know what could be happening? We have our url schema set too.

Comment: Can you share the link with which you are testing this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in the same boat and running out of ideas.

Comment: For me, it ended up being that I needed "applinks:" in front of each of my associated domain entries in the "Signing & Capabilities" tab in xcode. Now it opens the app first and then the app store, but app is opening with data so close enough I guess.